# How to maintain a set of integer sequences?

Tags: go, set, sequence

To construct a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), we can use [a map](https://yourbasic.org/golang/implement-set/):

```
set := make(map[string]bool)
set["Foo"] = true
foo_exists := set["Foo"]
```

What if we want a set of integer sequences? Go compiler complains `Invalid key type []int` for `make(map[[]int]bool)`.

Set is a commonly used basic data type that has a lot of uses. For example, a set of integer sequences can be used in a password generating/cracking program to record passwords that have been generated/tried. This enables the program to quickly look up generated/tried passwords to avoid generating/trying them again. This data structure is simply so basic that it should be expected to be used from time to time within various kinds of applications.

Comment: In general, though, it is possible to use the built in map to implement a "second order" hash map of the general type "map[int][]SomeCustomComparableType", where the primary key is a hash of the "SomeCustomComparableType" value.

Comment: @mkopriva I rephrased the question. I meant any integer sequences, not necessarily a Go array.

Comment: []int is not a "set" of integers, it is a slice which is a finite sequence of integers. As such it has more structure than a simple set. You have to decide on what type of equality on our "set of integer" you want: Extensional equality on sets or equality on finite sequences. You probably should redo the Tour of Go once more.

Comment: Okay, you clarified. You must find an injective map from []int (finite integers sequence) to a type usable as map key. There is no natural one, so you must decide. Turning []int to string via fmt.Print works well for short sequences. Encoding sequences as numbers (via std Gödel numbering) works well but gives huge numbers. Hashing might be a valid alternative.

Comment: Please demonstrate all intended use cases of this data type

Comment: if you can make assumptions about the integers that may appear in your sequences, you might be better off looking into alternative data structures, i.e. not necessarily a `map`; otherwise hashing

Answer (score 2):

As explained in @Wishwa Perera's answer, types which are not comparable are can not use as map key. So you can encode, or convert different type to your `int slices` and then insert to the map.

In below example, I convert int slice to string and insert to the map. But this is not good for long int slices because string is become more longer and more time consumed to run the code.

You can use hashing to solve that problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type intArray []int

func (i intArray) toString() string{
    return fmt.Sprintf(`%+v`, i)
}

func main()  {
    myMap := make(map[string]bool)
    arr1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    myMap[intArray(arr1).toString()] = true

    arr2 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    arr2Exist := myMap[intArray(arr2).toString()]
    fmt.Println(`is array 2 exist : `,arr2Exist) //is array 2 exist :  true

    arr3 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    arr3Exist := myMap[intArray(arr3).toString()]
    fmt.Println(`is array 3 exist : `,arr3Exist) //is array 3 exist :  false
}
```

You can run [here](https://play.golang.org/p/gPfaMdIwKyi)

Answer (score 1):

The map key can be any type that is comparable. Some of them are:

- Boolean
- Numeric
- String
- Pointer
- Channel
- Interface types
- Structs — if all it’s field type is comparable
- Array – if the type of value of array element is comparable

Some types which are not comparable and which cannot be used as a key in a map are:

- Slice
- Map
- Function

What you have used is a slice,use an array instead, define a size (let say 5) as `make(map[[5]int]bool)` and it will compile.

Comment: mh-cbon I think you are confused by the wording. the example shows to use an array instead of a slice. (never said [5]int is a slice)

Comment: `What you have used is a slice, define a size (let say 5) as make(map[[5]int]bool) and it will compile.` in this sentence the reader who does not make a difference will understand `[5]int` is a slice

Comment: Its unlikely with the prior description about comparable types. Anyway i have edited the answer. Thanks.